# Trying to ftp from a Google Cloud Engine VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

When trying to ftp from a GCE VM I just get a Connection timed out error. I can ping the ftp host and I can connect to it via ftp from a workstation on my office network, just not from any of my GCE instances.

Is Google blocking outbound FTP like they do SMTP? I searched their documentation and could find nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the problem wasn't the GCE itself, but the recipient's server was blocking the IP address for the GCE.